# Triggering Hardware Interrupt through Software with ARM Cortex A72

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, interrupt, arm64

I aim to measure latency between an interruption from the interruption getting caught to the waking up of the waiting task.

I am able to send a signal from a Kernel module to the task.

However, on my target, I haven't got any driver developped for GPIO that were my first try, so I can't pilot any gpio from the kernel module (gpio_export gives error 38).

So I wanted to generate an interrupt through software directly and not from an external signal on GPIOs.

I've found this [embetronicx tutorial](https://embetronicx.com/tutorials/linux/device-drivers/linux-device-driver-tutorial-part-13-interrupt-example-program-in-linux-kernel/#Triggering_Hardware_Interrupt_through_Software) that shows how to do it with x86 CPUs however, I can't find any similar solution with an A72 (Armv8) target. Do you have any tips ?

Comment: Cortex-A72 contains a GIC and the GIC can generate an interrupt though register writes.  This is 'point-0'  to an answer of your question.  How you want this to happen (through a Linux API with-in whatever kernel version/patches you use) is not currently defined by your question.  Linux already has code for GIC and you can find it in your software to decide how to better ask your question. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/irqchip/irq-gic-v4.c?h=v5.19-rc6

Comment: On modern systems interrupt is an exception, there are different ways how to make an exception in CPU.